# Не работает скрипт при упаковке pyinstaller --noconsole

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pyinstaller

Здравия!
Не работает скрипт, при попытке упаковать его в exe с аргументом --noconsole в pyintaller

Код:

```
import re
import subprocess
import os
 
devnull = subprocess.DEVNULL
output = subprocess.check_output("chcp 65001", shell=True, stderr=devnull, stdin=devnull)
arp = subprocess.check_output("arp -a", shell=True, stderr=devnull, stdin=devnull).decode("utf-8")
find = re.findall(r"---", arp, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Если упаковывать без аргумента --noconsole - то все работает.
Мое основное требование от скрипта - выполнение без открытия консоли.
(проблема возникает из-за этой строчки кода. Если ее закомментировать - скрипт будет выполняется с аргументом --nonconsole:

```
find = re.findall(r"---", arp, flags=re.UNICODE)
```